# Send email to admin during extension installation?

Tags: magento2, email, setup-script

I want to send an email to admin (website owner) to notify that our extension has been installed in your web store. For that, I have developing an extension but not getting any way to shoot the email using `InstallSchema` and `InstallData` setup scripts.

is there any specific way or setup script or event that can help me to send notification first time only?